# Library (package) or other tool to interface R with CloudSQL

Tags: google-apps, cloud-service, cloud-computing, r

Google has official Cloud SQL API client libraries for Java, PHP, Python and Go.

Is there any R package, tool, or workaround to use R directly with CloudSQL?

I know of such packages for the analogous Amazon Web Services, but I'm unaware of any for Google's cloud products.